# How to combine two generator sequences?

Tags: javascript

Given two sequences `g1` and `g2` computed by a generator how to combine them so that when `g1` is exhausted `g2` is outputted?

```
function* gen(x, y, step) {
    while(x < y) {
        x += step;
        yield x;
    }
};

let g1 = gen(1, 10, 1); 
let g2 = gen(1, 10, 2);

//How to merge g1 and g2 so that after g1 is exhasted g2 is shown?
current = g1.next().value;

while(current !== undefined) {
    console.log(current);
    current = g1.next().value;
}

console.log("done");
```

Comment: Have you tried placing g1 and g2 inside a third/master generator?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use generator function syntax again:

```
function* both() {
  yield* gen(1, 10, 1); 
  yield* gen(1, 10, 2);
}
const g3 = both();
for (const current of g3)
  console.log(current);
console.log("done");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the generators and `yield*` the generators.

```js
function* gen(x, y, step) {
    while(x < y) {
        x += step;
        yield x;
    }
};

function* sequence(...generators) {
    for (let g of generators) yield* g;
}

let g1 = gen(1, 10, 1),
    g2 = gen(1, 10, 2),
    gens = sequence(g1, g2),
    current = gens.next().value;

while(current !== undefined) {
    console.log(current);
    current = gens.next().value;
}

console.log("done");
```